# Javascript (jQuery) giving me strange results

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, html-table

Yesterday I started writing code for some random exercise I found on the internet.  My task was to have an empty HTML table and, when the user pressed one specific button, it would change the color of the cell to the opposite color (green or red) and change (add or deduct 1) its value.  After 10 cell clicks, it should alert a message with the average and some other things.  The first time I click the button, everything works fine.  However, for subsequent clicks it behaves strangely.  Here's some of the code

```
 //.....
var n=0;
$("#b1").click(function(){
  document.getElementById("b1").disabled = true; 
  $("td").removeClass();
  for (var i=0; i<25; i++)
  {
        var z=$("td").eq(i)
        z.text(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) ))
        if (z.text()<5)
        {
            z.addClass("linkClass")
        }
        else 
        {
            z.addClass("linkClass2")
        }
  }
  $("td").click(function(){
    n++;
    if ($(this).hasClass("linkClass"))
    {
        $(this).removeClass()
        $(this).text(parseInt($(this).text())-1);
        $(this).addClass("linkClass2")
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).removeClass()
        $(this).text(parseInt($(this).text())+1);
        $(this).addClass("linkClass")
    }
    if (n==10)
    {
        alert("Ten times clicked");
        document.getElementById("b1").disabled = false; 
        n=0;
    }
```

classes `linkClass` and `linkClass2` are just changing the background color of the cell.  Any ideas?

Comment: It would help people understand the issue if you could be a little more descriptive than "it behaves strangely".

Comment: well the second time i press the button to start and i click 5 cells the message 'Ten time clicks' pops.The third time it pops in even less clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move `$("td").click(function(){` out from `$("#b1").click(function(){` because each time when you click button you bind one more click on `td` so it performs several clicks in one time

Comment: should i create a new function and move the code there?if yes how should i call it?

Comment: @Alator. No, They just should be on the same level. Like: `$("#b1").click(function(){...}); $("td").click(function(){...});`

Comment: but they are on the same level aren't they? sorry for these many question im just new to all these.(could u please post a sample of it?)